# calling non https api url from https website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am trying to call non-https api url from my https website, but it gives me error.

jquery.js:9640 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://apiurl/imageapi.php'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'http://example.com/imageapi.php',
                method: 'post',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                dataType :'json',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    jQuery('.bfd-dropfield-inner').html('Procession............');
                },
                success: function(response) {
```

how can i solve this issue

Comment: If you can't get them to provide an HTTPS API, you'll need to run a proxy on your own server.

Comment: hey can you help me what you mean by proxy and how to make it work

Comment: A proxy is a script on your server that uses `curl` to connect to the API and return the response. See http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/